# Pushing view controller from AppDelegate - RESideMenu class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I am using RESideMenu class and using in content of this class navigation controller and in the left menu using some view.

This navigation is content main view and details view.

I want to push details view from app delegate when I receive notification, so I wrote that, but it's not working.

```
NSString *URL = @"any url";


UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mainNavigation = (UINavigationController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigation"];



MainViewController *mainVC = (MainViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
DetailViewController *detailVC = (DetailViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

[mainNavigation setViewControllers:@[mainVC, detailVC]];
[mainNavigation popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[detailVC setNewsLink:URL];
[mainNavigation pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Anyone can help?

[image]

---------------------**
update

```
RESideMenu *sideMenu = (RESideMenu *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewController"];
UINavigationController *mainNavigation = (UINavigationController *) [sideMenu contentViewController];

[mainNavigation pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: What kind of "not working"?  If you put a breakpoint in there, do you see all the controllers as valid objects?

Comment: Yes, I see all controllers and objects, but the details view not pushed

Comment: Any messages in the debug console?

Comment: See this image I don't use this Navigation on root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking "current navigation controller" and pushing to Details. You are instantiating a **new** mainNavigation (not current) and pushing to Details. You need to obtain **current** mainNavigation (storing in a property at startup, for example) and then pushing to new DetailViewController.

**UPDATE**

In that case, you are using RESideMenu. You have to take contentViewController (that may be a UINavigatorController) and push from it.

**Example**

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = (DetailViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

NSString *URL = @"any url";
[detailVC setNewsLink:URL];

[((UINavigationController *)self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewController) pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE 2**

Probably, in your AppDelegate, the RESideMenu is your self.window.rootViewController. Then:

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = (DetailViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

NSString *URL = @"any url";
[detailVC setNewsLink:URL];

RESideMenu *sideMenu = (RESideMenu *)self.window.rootViewController;
[((UINavigationController *)sideMenu.contentViewController) pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Still not working, and when I put break everything showed correctly, see update code

Comment: In your line: "RESideMenu *sideMenu = (RESideMenu *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewController"];" you are creating A NEW RESideMenu, not obtaining the current one. You have to store it in a property or take your self.window.rootViewController (that may be your menu). See my updated answer